# "Required permissions cannot be acquired" while debugging standalone application

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to debug a native application that uses some C# components but I'm getting a "Required permissions cannot be acquired" error when trying to start the application.
Now I did search StackOverflow and the net in general but all answers that I could find were related to ASP Web applications but the one I'm trying to debug is a standalone one.

Additional background: I'm using WinDbg to debug code that runs in a remote machine via remote terminal (in fact by using TWO remote connections since the machine in question is not reachable from my machine directly thanks to some stupid router configuration). The binaries are located on my computer and I access them via the auto drive mapping that RT does for me.

Now I did have similar issues in the past and I'm pretty sure that the code would run if I copy all the binaries to the target machine and start them from a local drive but this is something that I want to avoid.

NOTE: The code is targeting version 2.0 of the .Net Framework. The target machine does not have the configuration tool for .Net 2 installed and I gave up trying to install and make it run by hand to try to see if there is some "trust" setting that I can set to mke the code run..

Comment: Add the remote PC under a trusted zone.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do that?

Comment: I think you can do it via internet options or the caspol.exe. Sorry I have no more details :(

Comment: Thanks again (and correct me if I'm wrong) but I think that this would apply only for code that runs in the browser and what I'm dealing with is a standalone application. I think that I have to change something in the .net framework security settings but I don't know what (and I can't open the .Net configuration tool to start with), I thought that maybe there is some other easier solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem turned out to be a firewall issue and related to the fact that I could not reach the target machine (where the program was running) directly from my PC (where the executable files where located). I was connecting indirectly through another PC to the target machine and this was causing problems with the .Net security checks, after changing the switch/firewall so that I could connect directly I had no more problems.